# Dynamically re-assinging SQL query object with Python (Flask SQLAlchemy)

Tags: python, sql, flask, dynamic, sqlalchemy

I am new to Python, currently using it with Flask and SQLAlchemy to create queries and routes on my server.

The part I am focussing on for this question refers to the POST route that is responsible for updating information on the retrieved query object.

```
@app.route("/users/edit", methods=["POST"])
def edit_user():
id = request.form.get("userid")
attribute = request.form.get("attribute")
new_value = request.form.get("new_value")

if attribute == "first_name":
    user = User.query.filter(User.id == id).first()
    user.first_name = new_value
    db.session.commit()

if attribute == "last_name":
    user = User.query.filter(User.id == id).first()
    user.last_name = new_value
    db.session.commit()

if attribute == "image_url":
    user = User.query.filter(User.id == id).first()
    user.image_url = new_value
    db.session.commit()
```

Essentially depending on the attribute entered into the form, that particular property on the user object will be updated. This works no problem, but to avoid duplication I wonder is there a way to dynamically incorporate the attribute to avoid the duplication and only have one code block.

Something like user[attribute] = new_value

I have done this before but as the object is a returned query from SQL maybe it does not work the same way. I expected it would but it returns the error

```
 File "/Users/seanwhitty/Documents/SQL/flask-blogly/app.py", line 59, in edit_user
  user[attribute] = new_value
~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^
  TypeError: 'User' object does not support item assignment
```

I know there must be a simple solution, or something i am missing, but I can not seem to see it.

Comment: `setattr(user, attribute, new_value)` ?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your main question: do as the comment says

```
setattr(user, attribute, new_value)
```

But your code has problems, you must not mix session control with your app logic. You should use `scoped_session` and create a new session at the beginning of each http request, then commit/rollback it at the end of each request. OR use `autocommit=True` in sessionmaker